# Ecommerce cart - can ip of user be used instead of cookie based id?

Tags: php, session, cookies, e-commerce

I am developing an ecommerce site. The users need to be able to add products to the cart before they login i.e. users should be asked to login only when they checkout.

-->I know that this can be done by setting a session id and using it  for cart table in the database.

my question is:

- instead of using a cookie variable can we use the ip of the user?
  the ip will be used in the cart table.The cart cleanup policy etc.. will be the same as in the first case.
- if yes, what are the likely challenges for eg. like shared computer.
  if not, why?
- Is the first method i mentioned (using cookies), how e-commerce sites such as amazon etc manage their carts befor user login?

Comment: NO, ip!= user. amy people can share one IP. one person can use multiple IP's

Comment: A session is so simple to use, i dont know why you would consider any other approach

Comment: Great question. I also had the same doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP is not a useful identifier, many people in an office will share it, and on mobile networks there's often thousands of phones all mapped to the same IP. Even a single user might get bounced among many different IPs as they switch wireless networks but continue to use your site.

When dealing with a shared computer you can't be too concerned. Set your cookie to expire after a reasonable amount of time, maybe just hours, to avoid leaving a footprint in the browser permanently. If people are really concerned they can always use private browsing.

If you want to know how Amazon does this sort of thing, open your inspector and watch the network traffic, have a look at what cookies are assigned and how long they persist.

So the short answer is use a session and figure out how long a time limit you want it to persist for. I usually set these to 48 hours if not logged in, two weeks if logged in, but it really depends on your market.

I'd strongly advise you to evaluate off-the-shelf commerce packages like [Magento](https://magento.com) for PHP or [Spree](https://spreecommerce.com) for Ruby before going through the trouble of writing your own e-commerce platform from the ground up. This is usually a much larger undertaking than you anticipate at the start and there are a myriad of security concerns when dealing with money.

Comment: @BittoBennichan The best way to learn is by example, not from first principles when you've got no idea what makes a good e-commerce platform. If you've used Magento, Spree, Shopify and maybe a half dozen others *then* you're ready to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Well you kind of said it already but you can create a randomized 'token' that can be used to identify the customer. Theres a few ways to 'maintain state' with that token and the most common is with cookies. Otherwise in your website links you have to append the token. However - in the checkout process you don't need links you can do it all with form buttons, especially since you will have billing, shipping, etc forms to fill out.

So for the checkout process consider passing the token in a hidden form field and then you avoid cookies for the most important steps. You can also use that token in your order record table to associate the cart items. The token must have a randomized string but it can also contain useful data like date and time.